# Monitoring a file located in a SVN location using Geneos Active console

Tags: svn, monitoring, geneos

I have a file called latestReport.doc located in a SVN location - subversion.abc.com/svn/reports/. This file gets produced every day through an automated process. But some times the automated process fails and the new file is not produced. I need to monitor if the file present in the svn location is the latest or not. I want to do that using Geneos Active Console. Can this be done. If so then how, can some one please provide me the steps to set this up?

Comment: When you say produced everyday - do you mean it gets checked-in everyday. I mean does it get checked-in by some process and you need to check whether the file is checked-in or not.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the FTM plug-in.

File Transfer Monitoring can be configured to look for a file delivery everyday at a particular time (even if the file from yesterday is in the directory)

From the Help Files:

> **GENEOS UNIVERSAL FTM Plug-in** allows for monitoring arrival times of files.
>
> It is typically employed where the Exchange FTPs the previous day’s trading reports to the client. These reports are expected to arrive at pre-defined times so that they can be automatically picked up by the back office systems for further processing.
>
> If a report is late, but before the ‘drop dead’ time, it can be flagged as an amber warning condition. If the report is not available after the ‘drop dead’ time this can be flagged as a critical RED condition.
>
> For example: consider a report file that is expected to be FTPd from the Exchange at 05:00 with a back office system programmed to process it at 05:30. If the report arrives before 05:00 the FTM will show GREEN status, if the report arrives between 05:00 and 05:29:59 the status is AMBER and if the report has not arrived or arrived after the 05:29:59 the status is RED.
>
> FTM works by dividing the time into monitoring periods. By default, a monitoring period starts at 12:00 noon and finishes 11:59:59 the following day. FTM is aware of the current monitoring period and any files that exist, are ignored if their timestamp is outside of the monitoring period. This ensures that FTM monitors for ‘fresh’ file arrivals and does not confuse them with ‘older’ files that may be there from the previous monitoring period.
>
> It’s possible to switch the monitoring period between “noon to noon” (as described above) and “midnight to midnight”.